# long short portfolio in r

Tags: r, performanceanalytics

I'm trying to build portfolio with the function `Return.portfolio` (`PerformanceAnalytics` package). I have returns for 2 assets in a matrix `r`.
 when running: `Return.portfolio(r,verbose = T,weights = c(0.5,0.5))` it seems to working.
When trying to add rebalance `"quarters"` I'm getting this error:

```
"Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, k, , value = c(0.639312209726542, 0.639312209726542 : 
  subscript out of bounds".
```

and I don't understand what is wrong.
In addition, when trying to build long-short portfolio:
`Return.portfolio(r,weights = c(1,-1),verbose = T)`, its running but the results seems not logical.. Is there a reason for this?
thanks guys

Comment: The error you are getting suggests that your code is trying to subset an object beyond what it contains (e.g. taking the 3rd element of an object with 2 elements). However, other than that it is difficult to answer your question without a working example of your code :)

Comment: ok. the issue is that its working well untill i add the argument of rebalance.on, nothing else has change. (returns matrix is the same).

Comment: You need to provide an example for anyone here to be of any help to you.

Comment: ok, my returns matrix (r) looks like this:                                                          2002-01-01  0.0000000000  0.007576714
2002-01-02  0.0103941949  0.007895726
2002-01-03 -0.0005822981 -0.005968665                                                   returns till 12-08-2016.        when  trying to run this: Return.portfolio(r,verbose = T,weights = c(0.5,0.5),rebalance_on = "quarters") i gett this error: Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, k, , value = c(0.706865189567491, 0.706865189567491 : 
  subscript out of bounds. hope its help to understand.

Comment: Read this page to get a good idea of how to make a good example of the problem so someone can help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example